# Can't get Name on intermediate table base relation in a many-to-many relation

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Created a table with many to many relations with another, and on the basis of the intermediate table want to fetch fields name of the other one.

Here is table structure below:

School:

```
public partial class Schools
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    // Navigation       
    public ICollection<SchoolsSchoolType> SchoolsSchoolTypes { get; set; }     
}
```

SchoolType:

```
public class SchoolType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public ICollection<SchoolsSchoolType> SchoolsSchoolTypes { get; set; }
}
```

SchoolsSchoolType (It is Intermediate table)

```
 public class SchoolsSchoolType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ShoolId { get; set; }
    public Schools Schools { get; set; }

    public Guid SchoolTypeId { get; set; }
    public SchoolType SchoolType { get; set; }
}
```

Now call the table in the repository that is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Schools>> GetSchoolBySchoolId(Guid schoolId)
    {
        List<Schools> schools = null;
        schools = await _GpsContext.School.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ID == schoolId)
            .Include(sst => sst.SchoolsSchoolTypes)
            .ThenInclude(st=>st.SchoolType).ToListAsync();

        return schools;
    }
```

In controller code is following:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetforUpdateSchool(string schoolId)
    {
        var schools = await _schoolsRepository.GetSchoolBySchoolId(Guid.Parse(schoolId));
        List<SchoolUpdateBySchoolIdVm> schoolUpdateBySchoolIdVms = new List<SchoolUpdateBySchoolIdVm>();

        foreach (Schools school in schools)
        {
            schoolUpdateBySchoolIdVms.Add(new SchoolUpdateBySchoolIdVm
            {
                id = school.ID.ToString(),
                name = school.Name,
                schooltypeId = school.SchoolsSchoolTypes.Select(s => s.SchoolType.Id).ToString()

            }); ;

        }
        return Ok(schoolUpdateBySchoolIdVms);
    }
```

But here the output is giving error in the JSON.

```
[
{
    "id": "1cb0cd54-13e1-465a-8c1a-4699884f4c4c",
    "name": "Angela High School",
    "schooltypeId": "System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[DataLibrary.Data.SchoolModel.SchoolsSchoolType,System.Guid]" // Here is problem, want to get Id and name.
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line is wrong
`schooltypeId = school.SchoolsSchoolTypes.Select(s => s.SchoolType.Id).ToString()`
you've multiple `SchoolsSchoolTypes` so if you want it as string replace it with the following

```
schooltypeId = String.Join(',', school.SchoolsSchoolTypes.Select(s => s.SchoolType.Id.ToString()))
```

this will convert them to comma-separated values